# Can one use cardview for listview item and how

Tags: android, android-cardview

I would like to implement `CardView` in my app so that all `ListView` items are `CardView`s. Is it as simple as encapsulating a `ListView` item XML in `CardView`?

Comment: No, You have to use recyclerview instead of listview and add custom adapter with cardview.

Comment: of course you can. CardView is a FrameLayout

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Underneath `CardView` is just a simple `FrameLayout` that you could just inflate into a `ListView` (or `RecyclerView`).

Here's an example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/ly_root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FEFEFE"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_cover"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"/>

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And here's that example live in action:

[image]

Of course you would need to implement a custom adapter to wire them up together. But this is as with any custom `ListView` item really. There's nothing special about it.

Answer (score 34):

In case someone else come across this question, Other answers are right but then you should place your `CardView` within FrameLayout and you should make `ListView`'s divider transparent. `CardView`'s elevation and margin attribute won't work unless you use it inside `FrameLayout`.

Comment: In the docs it just says that it extends FrameLayout, wish they'd say it directly like you did. Thank you.

Comment: glad my answer is helping people.

Answer (score 9):

It's better to use CardView with RecyclerView, here is an example.

- **activity_main.xml (it contains the recyclerview)**

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- **cardview.xml**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
  android:layout_margin="10dp">
      <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text_cardview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="20dp" />
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
  ```
- **buid.gradle(Module:app)**

  ```
  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
      compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
  }
  ```
- **RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

  ```
  public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
      public ArrayList<String> myValues;
      public RecyclerViewAdapter (ArrayList<String> myValues){
          this.myValues= myValues;
      }

      @Override
      public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          View listItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview.xml, parent, false);
          return new MyViewHolder(listItem);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
           holder.myTextView.setText(myValues.get(position));
      }


      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
          return myValues.size();
      }

      public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
          private TextView myTextView;
          public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
              super(itemView);
          myTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_cardview);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **MainActivity.java**

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ArrayList<String> myValues = new ArrayList<String>();

      //Populate the ArrayList with your own values
      myValues.add("KitKat");
      myValues.add("Lollipop");
      myValues.add("Marshmallow");

      RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(myValues);
      RecyclerView myView =  (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
      myView.setHasFixedSize(true);
      myView.setAdapter(adapter);
      LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
      llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
      myView.setLayoutManager(llm);
   }     
   }
  ```

Refer to this tutorial for more details: [A Guide to Android RecyclerView and CardView](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I had to remove ".xml" from "R.layout.cardview.xml" in RecyclerViewAdapter.java

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use `CardView` for list item in ListView. But I suggest you to use RecyclerView instead of ListView, since it is the updated version of ListView. Check [this](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2014/10/recycleview-and-cardview-in-android.html) for RecyclerView with CardView.