# CardView attributes are not working with ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

I am trying to use ListView with CardView while my code is working fine and i can see a CardView in ListView but CardView elevation and padding is not working while it is working with RecyclerView. Am i the only one or this is the case with everybody ? What am i doing wrong ? I've tried setting listview divider but elevation doesn't work not matter what attributes i use on ListView or CardView!
I've tried  the following

[CardView elevation not working on Android 5.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773274/cardview-elevation-not-working-on-android-5-1-1)
&
[Elevation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572163/elevation-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751870/can-one-use-cardview-for-listview-item-and-how/) and answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664487/4587527). You'll get what you need.

you should place your `CardView` within `FrameLayout` even i suggest you to use `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Worked, thanks and sorry for asking such a silly question. i am a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little example of `ListView` and `CardView` and tested it with API-19 and API-24. https://github.com/AndroidAppNotes/ListView-and-CardView
[image: ListView-and-CardView]