# How to display listview items as items in e-commerce app?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-cardview

I am a new in android developerment, I am working on a project to display listview items like this

[image: picture]

My question is:

**How to write the XML layout to approximately achieve the same layout done in the picture?**

I have done some research and some work but I didn't find any answer.

This is my custom layout code

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adPic"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/adPic"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/adPrice"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:alpha=".87"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/row_black"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:alpha=".87"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/row_blue"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/adTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adTitle"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:alpha=".87"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/row_gray"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `Card View` approach to design this *layout*.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try that

Comment: Sorry, one more question:
it seems in  price field the background have a color and have also transparency in same way,how could the background color also have transparency?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in Photo that is not only list view  , its a card view ,here is link[Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) to learn how to creat cardview

Comment: Thanks Ameer i will see that

Comment: Wow that s what approximately what i am looking at !
Thanks Ameer Hamza.

I have another question but i don t know if i post it here or publish a new question !

Comment: you can comment here

Comment: Before this cardview i have a login page..i searched a lot and didn t find a solution ..how to customize my login layout to fit all screen size?
when testing on nexus4 all goes well and when i tested on my nexus9
a huge blank space is generated between textviews and editexts

Comment: create different layouts for tablets and handsets, beause tablets have more biger screen ,read this post you will get idea what i am saying http://stackoverflow.com/q/4185507/5727285 http://stackoverflow.com/q/24074226/5727285 https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: watch this video Supporting layouts tablets and Handsets https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mFQ389UzVA

Comment: Thanks a lot Ameer i am reading them carefully and i will post my comment soon if i get it

Comment: Sorry Ameer the videos related to supporting layouts tablets and handsets are for who used Fragment,but i am not using fragment anymore.
What should i do?

If i can pass u the xml file to check it ..

Comment: yas pass me your xml

Comment: please if u can send your email it s better than publishing layout here

Answer (score 2):

Just add this **compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'** in your gradel and in your xml under your linear layout do like this

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/adPic"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/adPic">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/adPrice"
                android:alpha=".87"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/row_black"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:alpha=".87"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/row_blue"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/adTitle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/adTitle"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:alpha=".87"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/row_gray"
                android:textSize="10dp"

                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

you can set the curve and corner radious as you want and you have to do the rest of the thing like the normal list view.

Comment: if the answer is correct then you can approve the ans by clicking the like button

Comment: Sry it s not correct i should use cardview with recyclerview instead of listview to achieve the image layout

Comment: You can use card view with list view also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751870/can-one-use-cardview-for-listview-item-and-how

Comment: recycler view is the advanced form of list view

Comment: plesure to help you bro cardview can be used with grid view also if you want you can up vote the ans too